# Is there any way to convert Point3D object of SymPy to tuple of coordinates?

Tags: python, sympy

I am writing a program to compute point of intersection of two lines using SymPy. I have used the following code:

`point3=l1.intersection(l2)`

`point3=tuple(point3)`

`print(point3)`

Here l1 and l2 are Line objects (again from Sympy)

This results in:

**Output:**

<<(Point3D(2, 1, 10),)

But, I need to perform iterations and comparisons many-a-times on the obtained point. So ,first i need to convert the Point object into tuple. I am not able to do this.

The problem is I am not able to extract this coordinates and fill a tuple, which is what I want to do.

Can someone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This intersection is a list. Apply tuple to the element in the list:

```
>> tuple(point3[0])
(2, 1, 10)
```